# JQuery switch statement (hide/show logic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How it should work: button "Show photo" opens "Content 1", "Show video" opens "Content 2", "Show map" opens "Content 4"

1. Switch-1 "Show photo" <-> "Show video".This mode works correctly
2. Switch-2 "Show map" -> "Show photo" or "Show video" (depending on
   Switch-1). After click button "Show map" instead "Close map" shown
   "Show photo" or "Show video" button

When "Content 4" is active, then it's possible to open "Content 1" or "Content 2 by click on "Show photo" or "Show video"

Nav structure is free to change.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.j-lst-toggle').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on('click', 'button', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $this.children().toggleClass('active');
      if ($this.hasClass('j-media-toggle')) {
        $this.closest('.j-multimedia-cnt').find('.j-media').children().toggleClass('active');
      } else if ($this.hasClass('j-map-toggle')) {
        $this.closest('.j-multimedia-cnt').find('.j-multimedia').children().toggleClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.j-multimedia-cnt {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.lst-c-actions {
  list-style: none;
}

.j-lst-toggle__btn {
  display: none;
}
.j-lst-toggle__btn.active {
  display: block;
}
.lst-c-actions__btn {
  display: none;
}
.lst-c-actions__btn.active {
  display: block;
}
.j-media__item {
  display: none;
}
.j-media__item.active {
  display: block;
}
.j-multimedia__item {
  display: none;
}
.j-multimedia__item.active {
  display: block;
}

.cols {
  display: flex;
}
.cols__item--left {
  width: 70%;
}
.cols__item--right {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="j-multimedia-cnt">
  <nav>
    <ul class="lst-c-actions">
      <li class="lst-c-actions__item j-lst-toggle j-media-toggle">
        <button type="button" class="lst-c-actions__btn btn-icon j-lst-toggle__btn active"><span class="btn-icon__ico icon video">icon-video</span> <span class="btn-icon__text">Show video</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="lst-c-actions__btn btn-icon j-lst-toggle__btn"><span class="btn-icon__ico icon photo">icon-photo</span> <span class="btn-icon__text">Show photo</span></button>
      </li>
      <li class="lst-c-actions__item j-lst-toggle j-map-toggle">
        <button type="button" class="lst-c-actions__btn btn-icon j-lst-toggle__btn active"><span class="btn-icon__ico icon map">icon-map</span> <span class="btn-icon__text">Show on map</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="lst-c-actions__btn btn-icon j-lst-toggle__btn"><span class="btn-icon__ico icon map">icon-map</span> <span class="btn-icon__text">Close map</span></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="j-multimedia">
    <div class="j-multimedia__item active">
      <div class="cols">
        <div class="cols__item cols__item--left">
          <div class="j-media">
            <div class="j-media__item active">
              <div style="background: red">Content 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="j-media__item">
              <div style="background: green">Content 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cols__item cols__item--right">
          <div style="background: grey">Content 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="j-multimedia__item">
      <div style="background: yellow">Content 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

"

Comment: What is the problem? It seems to work fine on your demo.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz instead "Close map" I need "Show photo" or "Show video" button with described functionality. And when "Content 4" is active I need "Show photo"( or "Show video) to open "Content 1" (or "Content 2"). I have no idea how to implement it. I've tried various combinations of nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to remove the "Close map" button and make the following changes to your event handler... First change the toggling of buttons to only hide your current button and show all other buttons:

```
$this.children().addClass('active'); // Show all buttons
$this.siblings().children().addClass('active');
$(this).removeClass('active'); // Hide clicked button
```

Then show specific media depending on the index of the button (you don't have them in the same order as the content numbers, hence showing the `1 - index`th element):

```
if ($this.hasClass('j-media-toggle')) {
    var media = $this.closest('.j-multimedia-cnt').find('.j-media').children();
    media.eq(1 - $(this).index()).addClass('active');
    media.eq($(this).index()).removeClass('active');
```

Finally toggle showing the media or map.

```
    media.closest('.j-multimedia').children(':has(.j-media)').addClass('active')
        .siblings().removeClass('active');
} else if ($this.hasClass('j-map-toggle')) {
    $this.closest('.j-multimedia-cnt').find('.j-multimedia').children()
        .toggleClass('active');
}
```

See this a full, working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v3Ld8u7L/1/